Open second terminal window in virtual environment
In Debian bookworm I opened a terminal window and then created and activated a virtual python environment with
python3 -m venv [path]

and activate.  This all worked fine.
Now I want to open a second terminal window in that same virtual environment - how do I do that?

Just open a new window and run the activate script in that window as well.

It turns out all I had to do was open another terminal window, and then
source [path_to_venv_folder]/bin/activate

This 'attached' (my word - don't know if it is correct) this terminal to the virtual environment.
